# Taking input in Java

Tags: java, input, user-input

I have some confusion if someone can help. Tried searching the web for it but didn't get any satisfying answer.

Why don't we simply use `System.in.somemethod()` to take input in Java just like we do for output? Like `System.out.println()` is used so why not `System.in` as it is? Why is there a long process for Input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking input from the command line will always be trickier than just outputting data. This is because there is no way to know that the input is semantically correct, structured correctly or even syntactically correct.

If you just want to read *bytes* from `System.in` then a lot of the *uncertainty* of the input disappears. In that case there is only two things to take into account: I/O errors and end-of-input - both of which are also present for `System.out`. The only other thing that may be tricky is that `InputStream` may not return all the bytes that are requested in a single call to `read`.

So reading data from `System.in` isn't hard; *interpreting* the data - which often comes down to parsing the data or validating the data - is the hard part. And that's why often the `Scanner` class is used to make sense of the input.

Answer (score 5):

The only methods that `System.in`, an [`InputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html), provides are the overloads of `read`. Sure, you could do something like:

```
    byte[] bytes = new byte[5];
    System.in.read(bytes);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bytes));
```

to read five bytes from the console. But this has the following disadvantages:

- You need to handle the checked `IOException`. (not shown in the code snippet above)
- Hard to work with bytes. (unless you want them specifically)
- You usually just want to read the input until the end of a line. With this it's hard to know where the end of a line is.

So that's why people use `Scanner`s to wrap the `System.in` stream into something more user-friendly.

Comment: So System.in.read would only work with bytes? No other data type?

Comment: @SQR That's right. You can convert bytes to a string though. But I would rather use a `Scanner`.

Comment: One more thing.. What's the better way? Scanner or InputStreamReader?

Comment: @SQR Definitely `Scanner` in my opinion. `Scanner` is way more powerful, unless your requirements suggest that you need to work with individual bytes, which is quite rare.

Comment: @SQR if you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that check mark!

Answer (score -2):

Just as you cannot use `System.out.somemethod()` instead of `System.out.println()` in the same way you cannot use `System.in.somemethod()` instead of `System.in.read()`.

Comment: I think that you're taking this a bit too literally.

Comment: Just being general. Actually I'm not a professional developer yet so I apologize for any mistakes.

Comment: Please, don't apologize for not being a "professional" - whatever that means. There are a lot of "amateurs" that are better than some of the professionals out there. The point of `somemethod` is that you could replace it with any other method name *such as* `read`. It's not the actual name for a method. Note that you can back ticks \` to indicate code within your answer. Due to the misunderstanding this was not the best answer, but please do come and try again.

Comment: After assuming the person reading my answer is not dumb actually I didn't use the back ticks just to denote a method. Well I'll remember your tip next time. And please have a look at the link.
[Treehouse](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/how-to-take-console-input-in-java-using-systeminread)

Comment: That link has some issues with it. As you don't know the encoding used by the system, you may get different values even if the input is the same character. The input character could be encoded using UTF-8 or Windows-1252 depending on the system, which means different values for characters that are not US-ASCII. For UTF-16BE input you could even get decimal `0` in return - even for the character `9` as in the example. Or `FF` / `FE` if a BOM is present at the start of the input.